# Don't hide the "Votes" tab behind "More" in Tagged Questions page

Tags: feature-request, tabs, custom-filters

One of the most used and useful sort options is by votes. When going to sort by votes some tagged questions, I was surprised to see it's not easily accessible:

> [image]

Can the "Votes" tab please be added to the "Newest", "Active", etc, and not hidden away?

Comment: Glad to see I'm not the only one bothered by this.

Comment: Ditto. After "Newest", I have always used "Votes". "Active" can be rendered useless often (say, a zealous editor), and "votes" is almost exclusively what I sort as in new sites, searches, etc.

Comment: It's not just hidden as a choice, worse news is that if you choose "Frequent" or "Votes" sort order then the *chooser* closes back up; hiding **which** sort order you have chosen. It's usually obvious if the "Votes" sort order is chosen (depending upon the newness of the site), but the "Frequent" vs. the others might not be so obvious. Needs some redesign.

Answer (score 3):

They should simply move the questions count and [Filter] cog up one line.

Before:

[image: Current appearance of Meta's "All Questions" webpage]

Having a single questions webpage (with all choices simultaneously visible) that can use tabs to select sorting order (and content preference) provides a cleaner UI.

**After**:

[image: New appearance of Meta's "All Questions" webpage]

That's a better user experience because you only need the **one** "Questions" webpage (instead of one for "[Top Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)" and another for "[All Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions)", or "[Question Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-filters)") with **all choices visible** (and consistent tab naming, instead of "Featured" on one and "Bounties" on the other, or "Frequent" (hidden) on one and "Active" on the other).

Note: "Active" is a sort order (determined by bumping), while "Hot" doesn't *need* bumping and considers the recent (few days) views, much as "Week" and "Month" do for their respective durations.

I slightly increased the size of the 'tab bar', it could be reduced if an additional choice is to be added later. Similarly, a choice could easily be deleted if needed without leaving the space barren. Disclaimer: Editing of images done on a cellphone.

---

Not shown, or part of this feature request:

The [Filter] cog pulldown could house the user's (possibly lengthy) list of user defined Filters, and a checkbox beside each preconfigured filter could allow altering (editing) existing choices easily (uncheck to complete editing and save).

Alternative [Tag view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-filters) example:

[image: Alternative option to use larger 'tab bar' with more visible options]